# Azure queue trigger failing on deployment, strange connection string requirement

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

On deployment, a function app with a new queue trigger is firing an error that looks like this:

```
The 'MyQueueTrigger' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'MyQueueTrigger'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Queues: Storage account connection string 'AzureWebJobsAzureStorageConnectionString' does not exist. Make sure that it is a defined App Setting.
```

In code (C#), this trigger looks like this:

```
       [FunctionName("MyQueueTrigger")]
        public async Task Run(
                [QueueTrigger(
                    StorageConstants.MyQueue,
                    Connection = StorageConstants.AzureStorageConnectionString
                )]
                string myQueueItem,
                ILogger log)
        {
         ...
        }
```

The constants described here are literally:
"%MyQueue%"
and
"AzureStorageConnectionString", respectively

Post-deployment, navigating in the Azure portal to this function -> Code + Test shows the following:

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator-4.1.1",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "connection": "AzureStorageConnectionString",
      "queueName": "%MyQueue%",
      "name": "myQueueItem"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/MyNamespace.Functions.dll",
  "entryPoint": "Redacted"
}
```

This function gets disabled on deployment/startup after the error above. The phrase "AzureWebJobsAzureStorageConnectionString" does not appear anywhere in my function app, although AzureWebJobsStorage and AzureStorageConnectionString are both required default settings. Where could I look for this concatenated string looking thing?

Adding a configuration with this Name *does* resolve the issue, but I don't want to commit to doing this ongoing.

Also, this queue trigger works as expected when running locally. local.settings.json looks like this:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureStorageConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=redacted;AccountKey=redacted==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "fooBlobContainer": "foo-blob-container",
    "myQueue":  "my-queue"
  },
  "AppSettings": {
    "KeyVaultSecrets": {
      "KeyVaultName": "https://redacted.vault.azure.net",
      "DataWarehouseConnection": "DataWarehouseConnection",
      "LoggingDBConnectionString": "LoggingDBConnectionString",
      "ClientId": "redacted"
    },
    "myServiceAPI": {
      "BaseURL": "redacted.azurewebsites.net/"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you create an azure function app, the function runtime requires a storage account to run from. This storage account will be used by your function app to manage all your triggers and other BAU files.
As you've not set this value for your function app, it fails. Just point your existing storage account to this configuration and it should work.

The `AzureStorageConnectionString` your are referring to is just the config you use for the storage account your queue resides it. You can either use the same storage account for the `AzureWebJobsAzureStorageConnectionString` config to hold the func app files there, or use a separate storage account for the func app.

**Bottom line is :** your func app requires a storage account in order to run/work. :)

See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsstorage
[image]

Comment: Right, this is a crucial part of the function app that does exist - timed triggers that are part of this function app place run info in this account. 

The queue trigger is the only one looking specifically for this "AzureWebJobsAzureStorageConnectionString", which looks like a concatenated nightmare I can't find anywhere in code.

Comment: can you confirm that if you update the above function code to use an HTTP trigger instead of a Queue trigger it works and runs fine without throwing an error asking for a AzureStorageConnectionString?

Comment: Timed triggers, and a custom health HTTP trigger that looks like the following, work fine:

        [FunctionName("Health")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "health")] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {

Comment: are you getting the same error with running this locally on your machine in visual studio? or does this fail only in the deployed azure cloud instance? if so, can you also share your function local settings json file config?

Comment: Running locally works just fine, and I've updated my post with the local.settings.json

This only causes initial failure when deployed to an azure function instance. Nothing in our deployment process contains this setting name I'm seeing errors about. If deployment scripting is involved in this issue, though, what property in a function app deployment sets this?

Comment: Ah lord you're onto it, from MSFT: If the app setting name begins with "AzureWebJobs", you can specify only the remainder of the name here. For example, if you set connection to "MyStorage", the Functions runtime looks for an app setting that is named AzureWebJobsMyStorage

Comment: Thats so annoying by Microsoft haha. Glad you figured it out. Cheers!